# Deploy and manage WebApp with AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-opsworks, amazon-ecs

I’m noob with AWS services, I develop web application with Ruby on Rails, so, I’ll like to know what could be the best way or the right one to deploy and manage web application with AWS.

Right now there are bunch of services of AWS for handle web apps, but I’m not sure which service to use, OpsWork, EC2 (setup the entire server), Elastic Beanstalk or EC2 Containers and so on…

Well, I have 3 small apps from diferentes clients and I’m looking the right way to have them on one instance or couples of instances, right know i’m with OpsWorks, I have 3 stack, one for each web app, I want to know if I can deploy and manage those apps in one stack and 2 instance of OpsWorks or there are better way or other services as IaaS or PaaS solutions?. So i’m looking for advise or orientation for use AWS service for those kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather vague and the answer depends on the needs of your app, but I'll give my 2 cents regardless.  I have several rails apps hosted on EC2 instances running Ubuntu, NGINX, and Phusion Passenger.  The apps that receive a decent amount of traffic and require consistent performance/availability are cloned across multiple EC2 instances (in multiple zones) and have traffic managed by Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs).  The app databases are served through amazon's RDS services.  Domain registration and nameservers are set up through AWS Route 53.  Static assets are served from AWS S3.

This type of architecture certainly has a price tag on it and isn't the only way to do it. My experience has been that all of my older Rails apps have survived over a year with 100% uptime and rarely have moments of slowness been the fault of AWS as opposed to my own code or 3rd-party software.

Hope this helps; feel free to ask questions.